# How can I delete cookies for a specific site in chrome in android

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android

I can see 'Settings' -> 'Privacy' -> 'CLEAR BROWSING DATA', but that will clear my browsing info for all sites. I can also see under 'Settings' -> 'Site settings', there is an option to select 'All sites' and then pick a specific site. However, the site that has a cookie that I want to delete is not in that list (perhaps that list is only sites that have more than just cookies set?).

I also tried navigating to chrome://settings/cookies (which works in the desktop browser), but this doesn't work in the mobile browser.

Answer (score 25):

Press the favicon for the site and a pop-up will allow you to change a few settings for that specific site including removing data like cookies, just did it, Android 6.01, works.

Comment: In Chrome 108 on Android 13, I have this: tap icon to left of address bar; tap "Cookies and site data"; I see "199 cookies in use" and I tap the trash bin icon, tap Delete to confirm; afterwards, though, it still says "199 cookies in use".

Comment: It's been like this for a long time, too - I had the same problem on my Pixel 2XL for as long as I can remember.

Answer (score 9):

Settings → (under Advanced) Site settings → All sites

Select the site you want and under Usage you can clear any stored data, includes cookies. You can also Clear & Reset.

I do not think there is a way to clear only cookies but this will allow you to clear data for individual sites.

Comment: No, as I clearly wrote in my original question, I already found that settings area, but the site I want to delete a cookie (or all cookies, or even all site data) from doesn't appear in that list.

Comment: Oh I see. Under Site settings, does the site show up under Storage? It's strange that it has a cookie but isn't in the list.

Comment: I can only delete data for a specific time span but not for specific site I want

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Menu (the 3 vertical dots on top right of screen)
2. Cilck History
3. Click the Search magnifying glass
4. Enter the name of the site OR you can be less specific so you pull up EVERYTHING with the site name....Example....you want to clear cookies from www.butterball.com.  Enter "butterball" and all sites, including search pages, will be listed in your resulting History.  (If you want to clear cookies from just one site, put that site's specific URL.)
5. Click the Trash icon next to each site in the History list (ALL of them)
6. ALL your cookies for your "blocked" site are cleared
7. Now try the site...it worked, right???? :-)

Comment: I don't believe history entries would clear any cookies. For the site I'd like to delete cookies for I have about 100 history entries...